Using cluster option in mediate function
I am trying to conduct a mediation analysis with multi-level data, i.e., individual observations nested in countries. To control for the clustered structure, I want to use the "cluster" option of the mediation package in R.
However, I get the following error message:

Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In mediate(model.m, model.y, sims = 50, treat = "treat", mediator
= "med",  :   length of cluster vector differs from # of obs for mediator model

There are 112 levels to the grouping variable. I tried to replicate the data, but I cannot get the exact same error message. However, similarly to the actual regression I am running, the code below only works without the cluster option. So I would hope that if I understand what is wrong in the replication example below, I will also figure out the error with my actual data.
df <- data.frame(
  med = sample(1:4, 5000, replace = TRUE),  
  outcome = sample(c(0, 1), 5000, replace = TRUE),  
  predictor = runif(5000, 0, 12),  
  group_var = sample(1:50, 5000, replace = TRUE)  
)

model.m <- lm(med ~  predictor, data=df)

model.y <- glm(outcome ~  predictor + med, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))

out.1 <- mediate(model.m, model.y, sims = 50, treat = "predictor", mediator = "med", cluster = "group_var")

Both in the actual data and the replication data above I tried transforming the group variable into a factor variable and to generate a vector from the data to use as a grouping variable:
outputVector <- as.numeric(levels(df$group_var)[as.integer(df$group_var)])

